# Issue Installing Kapua on windows

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, docker, docker-compose, kapua

When ran the **./dcoker-compose.sh** command in the power shell, got the following error:

```
Deploying Eclipse Kapua...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker\api\client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "docker\api\daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "docker\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "docker\api\client.py", line 237, in _get
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http\client.py", line 1255, in request
  File "http\client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
  File "http\client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
  File "http\client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
  File "http\client.py", line 950, in send
  File "docker\transport\npipeconn.py", line 32, in connect
  File "docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 23, in wrapped
  File "docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 72, in connect
  File "docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 52, in connect
pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 81, in main
  File "compose\cli\main.py", line 200, in perform_command
  File "compose\cli\command.py", line 60, in project_from_options
  File "compose\cli\command.py", line 152, in get_project
  File "compose\cli\docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
  File "compose\cli\docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "docker\api\client.py", line 197, in __init__
  File "docker\api\client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')
[2908] Failed to execute script docker-compose
Deploying Eclipse Kapua... DONE!
Run "docker-compose -f D:\3. Programs\Kaupa\kapua\deployment\docker\win\..\compose\docker-compose.yml logs -f" for container logs
```

how this issue can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

This is because, Docker is not running on the PC, once the Docker Desktop is up and running then re-ran the command. This error got resolved !!